# cURL to Invoke-Webrequest command

Tags: powershell, curl, invoke-webrequest

Can anyone give me a hint, how to convert following curl command to PS Invoke-Webrequest ?

```
curl -d {\"password\":\"$password\"\} $vault/v1/auth/userpass/login/${login,,}
```

I have some thoughts on this, but cannot figure out, how to finish this:

```
$vault="3.3.3.3:8500"
$pair = (Get-Credential)
$params = ????
$login = $pair.getNetworkCredential().username
$pass = $pair.getNetworkCredential().password

Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Post -Credential $pair -Body $params -UseBasicParsing
```

How to correctly pass $params like in curl request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Params should be a hashtable `@{}`.

```
$Params = @{
    Username="TestName";
    Password="TestPassword";
    Places = @("Here","There");
}
```

Here is a example using a test API called jsonplaceholder

```
$url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'

$params = @{
    title: 'foo'
    body: 'bar'
    userId:1
}

(Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Post -Body $params -UseBasicParsing).content | ConvertFrom-JSON
```

Response

```
                                                     id
title: 'foo'                                       
body: 'bar'                                        
userId:1                                           

---------------------------------------------------  --
                                                    101
```